# Android Room DAO how to run several DAO methods in a single transaction?

Tags: java, android, transactions, android-room

Consider the following Room DAO

```
@Dao
public abstract class JobDao {

    @Insert
    public abstract long insert( Job v );

    @Update 
    public abstract int update( Job v );

    @Insert 
    public abstract long insertPerson( Person p );

    @Update
    public abstract int updatePerson( Person p );

    @Transaction
    public void insertNetJobs( List<NetJob> list ) {
         Timber.d("--- insert page start");
         for( NetJob j : list ) {
             if ( updatePerson( j.getPerson() ) == 0 ) {
                insertPerson( j.getPerson() );
             }

             insert( j.getJob() );
         } 
         Timber.d("--- insert page end");
    }  
}
```

According to documentation anything inside method marked with @Transaction runs in a single transaction. But in reality it runs one transaction for entire method insertNetJobs and inner transaction for each call  updatePerson, insertPerson, insert. So the log looks like that

```
D/JobDao: ---- insert page start
D/SQLiteDatabase: beginTransaction() 
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
                  beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
                  beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
                  beginTransaction()
........................
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
                  beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
                  beginTransaction()
D/SQLiteDatabase: endTransaction()
D/JobDao: ---- insert page end
```

As the result the method insertNetJobs works very slow. Is there any possibility to run this method using the only one transaction?

Comment: "As the result the method insertNetJobs works very slow" -- what evidence do you have that nested transactions is the cause?

Comment: How are logging the transactions? I am pretty sure that if you add the `@transaction` annotation it runs everything in that function in one transaction. [See](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction)

Comment: @insa_c I am pretty sure about nested transactions, if you take a look at a generated code for the DAO class it's obvious

Comment: @CommonsWare My past experience tells me that nested transactions slow down the executions but maybe I am wrong I'll take some extra measurements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what is the problem. In case somebody has a similar problem here is an explanation. Actual problem was with the update query. It took about 20ms to execute it.

This code:

```
   @Update
   public abstract int updatePerson( Person p );
```

Generates the following query:

```
UPDATE OR ABORT `sw_person` SET `id` = ?,`id_s` = ?,`id_lang` = ?,`name` = ? WHERE `id` = ?
```

This query updates the pk of the person's table but in the other tables this key is used as a fk which causes to look up among those tables. It's a pity that "room" updates pk in update query, probably the solutions is to write query manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  roomDB.runInTransaction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Timber.d("--- insert page start");
            for( NetJob j : list ) {
                if ( updatePerson( j.getPerson() ) == 0 ) {
                    insertPerson( j.getPerson() );
                }

                insert( j.getJob() );
            } 
             Timber.d("--- insert page end");
        }
    });
```